# c# Pulling Object Location and outputing to variable from AD

Tags: c#, arrays, string, parsing

I'm writing an AD program for my company and I'm trying to pull down the OU location for an object. I can pull the DistinguishedName, but I want to truncate the object down, removing the object name and only having the container.

Example:

```
CN=Adam Smith,OU=User,OU=CityName,DN=Domain,DC=Domain2
```

I want to parse it to either

```
OU=User,OU=CityName,DC=Domain,DC=Domain2
or only the OU.
```

I'm trying to separate it into an array by using

```
string _UserDN = (string)searchResult.Properties["distinguishedName"][0];
var userdnsplitarray = _UserDN.Split(',');
```

And I can truncate it that way but I'm not sure how to rejoin using either array[2,3] or array[1,2,3,4]

Also this solution would have to work because some of the tree has an extra branch, some of the ou's have an additional OU to work with.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
enter code here
```

Comment: The Dictionary Answer worked out very well with very little tweaking.  It gave me exactly what I needed.  Thank you for all the help.

Answer (score 0):

Providing that

```
string _UserDN = (string)searchResult.Properties["distinguishedName"][0];
```

returns is in the correct format, I suggest converting (parsing) the initial `string` into a *dictionary*, e.g.

```
  using System.Linq;
  using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

  ...   

  string _UserDN = "CN=Adam Smith,OU=User,OU=CityName,DN=Domain,DC=Domain2";

  Dictionary<string, string[]> data = _Regex
   .Split(_UserDN, @"(?<!\\),") // We split on unescaped commas only
   .Select(item => item.Split(new char[] { '=' }, 2))
   .Where(pair => pair.Length >= 2)
   .GroupBy(pair => pair[0], 
            pair => pair[1]
              .Replace(@"\,", ",")
              .Replace(@"\\", @"\"), // drop escapements
            StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
   .ToDictionary(chunk => chunk.Key,
                 chunk => chunk.ToArray());
```

Test:

```
  String test = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, data
    .Select(pair => $"{pair.Key} : [{string.Join(", ", pair.Value)}]"));

  Console.Test(test);
```

Outcome:

```
  CN : [Adam Smith]
  OU : [User, CityName]
  DN : [Domain]
  DC : [Domain2]
```

Having the dictionary you can easily query it, e.g.

```
 // Do we have OU?
 bool hasOU = data.ContainsKey("OU");
 // How many OU do we have?
 int ouCount = data.ContainsKey("OU") ? data["OU"].Length : 0;
 // What do we have in "OU" key?
 if (data.TryGetValue("OU", out var values)) {
   // values is the array which contains all the OU values: ["User", "CityName"]
 }
 else {
   // No OU, no values 
 }  

 // Let's remove CN key: OU=User,OU=CityName,DN=Domain,DC=Domain2 
 string noCNString = string.Join(",", data
   .Where(pair => pair.Key != "CN")
   .Select(pair => string.Join(",", pair.Value
     .Select(value => $"{pair.Key}={value.Replace(@"\", @"\\").Replace(",", @"\,")}"))));
```

Comment: Be aware that users can exist in the built-in containers, like Users, but the DN for that is prefixed with CN, not OU. e.g. CN=Users,DN=Domain,DC=Domain2

Comment: @Gabriel Luci: I see, thank you! However, I think that the main principle - building a *dictionary* and quering the  dictionary, not the initial `string` remains the same. Another "thank you" for the escapment which you've mentioned in your answer ("unescaped comma")

Comment: The Dictionary Answer worked out very well with very little tweaking.  It gave me exactly what I needed.  Thank you for all the help.

Answer (score 0):

The OU portion will start at the first unescaped comma (not preceded with `\`). You can do something like this to find it:

```
string dn = "CN=Adam Smith,OU=User,OU=CityName,DN=Domain,DC=Domain2";

int indexOfComma = -1;
do {
    indexOfComma = dn.IndexOf(',', indexOfComma + 1);
} while (indexOfComma != 0 && dn[indexOfComma - 1] == '\\');

var ou = dn.Substring(indexOfComma + 1);
```

That'll leave you with `OU=User,OU=CityName,DN=Domain,DC=Domain2`.

I see you're using a search result, so this question makes sense. But if you have another case where you have a `DirectoryEntry` of an AD object, be aware that you can use the [`Parent`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-ca/dotnet/api/system.directoryservices.directoryentry.parent) property and just pull the `distinguishedName` of that.